# Rust idiomatic choice between implementing methods for a struct or pass that struct to function

Tags: rust

I frequently ask myself what would be the most idiomatic way of organizing code between methods in the struct impl (something that looks more object oriented), and functions that will process this struct (something I'd say more data oriented).

As I couldn't find anything about it, I decided to ask here if someone has this information, or some insight about it.

Here are simple case of what I mean for the two approach.

Method implementation (object oriented):

```
struct Merger {
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
}

impl Merger {
    pub fn merge(&self, data_to_merge: Vec<String>) -> String {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Function implementation (data oriented ?):

```
struct MergeConfig {
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
}

fn merge(conf: &MergeConfig, data_to_merge: Vec<String>) -> String {
    // do stuff...
}
```

So my questions are:

- What is the most idiomatic way to structure code ?
- And if it's more a design choice, what are the typical use cases for each way ? (as both seems to be valid in any cases)

Comment: Its purely opinion based. I personally would use a method on a struct if needs to access its (private) internals. And an external method otherwise. For example, if I would like to write a serializer, I would even go as far as creating a separate trait with a method that accepts ref to object and returns a string. And then a separate type implementing the trait. It would be weird to put this on the original struct itself, considering that maybe you would like to use multiple different serializers. But as I said: this is opinion based.

Comment: These guidelines might be helpful: https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/predictability.html#c-method

> Functions with a clear receiver are methods

Answer (score 1):

The [API guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/predictability.html#c-method) say that this specific example should be a method on `Merger`.

An immediate benefit of using a method over a function is that you don't have to import or qualify the function, instead you simply do `config.merge(data)`, and it'll work in all contexts without imports or qualifying `merge`